# How to get compact data (without whitespaces) from Google Directions API?

Tags: web-services, google-maps

Hi all I'm using [Google Directions API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/) and the data returned from a test query look like this:

[Example](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Boston,MA&destination=Concord,MA&waypoints=Charlestown,MA%7CLexington,MA&sensor=false):

```
{    "routes" : [
      {
         "bounds" : {
            "northeast" : {
               "lat" : 42.46015000
                      .. .. ..
```

I was wondering is there an option I can specify to get the data in *compact-mode* (without the whitespaces) ?

Comment: For what reason you need this?

Comment: @ArgiropoulosStavros Since I'm getting the data and removing all the whitespaces, I was wondering if there's an option that already sends the data with whitespace stripped.

Comment: I mean is it a performance issue?You try to reduce the size of the responce?Cause i assume you are consuming the json with some kind of parser are you?I'm just trying to understand the purpose of your question to try to help you.

Comment: @ArgiropoulosStavros +1. Yes I'm trying to reduce the size of the response. This will reduce unnecessary network traffic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option is not available.

Comment: I'm trying to reduce the size of the response. This will reduce unnecessary network traffic.

Comment: Got it.  Unfortunately you'll have to continue to use your current implementation.